# Ignore Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slidedown

So I've got an div that slides down when you scroll near the bottom of the page. In that div, I have an "X" anchor that slides it up again (this is in jQuery). But if I scroll, the div slides down again (naturally). So I want the X to first of all, make "#topDiv" slide up, and then ignore the function that makes it slideDown.

Full code:

```
  $("#topDiv").hide();

  $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500) {
          $("#topDiv").slideDown();
      }


      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 800) {

          $("#topDiv").slideUp();
      }
      $("#closeTop").click(function () {
          $("#topDiv").slideUp();
          return false;
      });
  });
```

[Demo Page](http://tutorials.underbakke.net/js/function/) ( http://tutorials.underbakke.net/js/function/ )

Answer (score 3):

You could use the on/off methods to unbind the slidedown after the "X" is clicked

```
$("#topDiv").hide();

$(window).on('scroll', showTopDiv);

function showTopDiv() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500) {
          $("#topDiv").slideDown();
      }
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 800) {
          $("#topDiv").slideUp();
      }
});

$("#closeTop").click(function () {
      $("#topDiv").slideUp();
      $(window).off('scroll', showTopDiv);
      return false;
});
```

Also, in your slideup function, adding `$("#topDiv").is(':visible')` to the if statement will make sure it is'nt executed uneccessary.

And is there really a need to bind the click function on every scroll?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#topDiv").hide();

$(window).addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500) {
      $("#topDiv").slideDown();
  }


  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 800) {
      $("#topDiv").slideUp();
  }

  $("#closeTop").click(function () {
      $("#topDiv").slideUp();
      $(window).removeEventListener('scroll',arguments.callee,false);
  });
}
```